# Hosting Web Application on WinCE 6.0 or 7.0

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, web, windows-ce

I have WinCE 6.0 as well as WinCE 7.0 running devices. I wanted to host a web application and access it from outside the device. So I included web server in OS and i was able to access simple HTML Page. Now my requirement is to host a web application in WinCE Device and access SQLCE or SQlite database from the same and access the application remotely. 
When I googled I came to know that ASP.Net is not supported. So which technology will be very good to develop and host web application to satisfy my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows CE you can use "old-style" ASP, mixing HTML and vbscript or javascript code to generate dynamic content. From the scripts you can access COM objects (that needs to be implemented in native code) and use them to access your data.
If you want to use managed code you may give a look at padarn:
http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Padarn.aspx